# Can not log in into Azure account from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, cloud, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to log on my Azure subscription from Visual Studio 2019 and I get this message:

> We Could not refresh the credentials for the account.
> The authorization server returned an invalid response.

[image: Error Visual Studio 2019]

Comment: I also encounter this problem, help->send feedback->report a problem, in this page you could login and you vs will login too. Maybe you could have a try.

Comment: You should check with MS support and not on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 6):

Share my solution:

In Visual Studio go to Options/Environment/Accounts and select "System Web Browser"

The next attempt to login was succeful.

Comment: Good job! Stupid Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is still good for VS 2022 V17.5.5, the latest version as of today (2023-05-03)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below:

1. Open Visual Studio as Admin and then try again
2. Update Visual Studio to latest release and restart your PC
3. Open Visual Studio. Click Help, Send Feedback, Report a Problem.
   This brings you to a login screen. If you log in from there, it will log you into Visual Studio

Comment: Sorry, I already tried these steps and not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me following steps works.( solved )

1. Closed all instances of visual studio.
2. go to windows. open run command write %temp% . deleted all temp files and
3. restart the pc , open visual studio with admin account and login with my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.11.30 from 16.11.8 and rebooting the error went away.